# Remove largest and lowest number from a 2d array without sorting

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but this is what I have so far:

```
int main(){
int foo[5][5]; //assume it is filled with postive numbers THERE ARE repeated numbers
int i, j; 
int a =0 ; //biggest
int b = 0; //smallest

for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
        if (a>foo[i][j])
            a = foo[i][j];
        if (b<foo[i][j])
            b = foo[i][j];
    }
}


}
```

But after this now that I have the largest and smallest number for each col. How do I replace them in the arr? Is this even the right way?

EDIT: 
I want to remove the largest and smallest number from each row in my 2d array. For example if a row looks like this: 3 5 1 3 11 2 afterwords it should look like 3 5 3 2. The 1 and 11 have been removed. 
I would really be grateful for any help. Thanks!

EDIT 2: 
I want to remove the lowest and greatest from each row. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: You should probably provide an actual example of your array before and after showing what you want to happen to the remaining elements, as it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Start with `int b = a = foo[0][0];` and the inner loop at `j = 1`. In case the smallest element is bigger than 0. And if the values in the matrix are always positive: use `unsigned int`.

Comment: I want to remove the largest and smallest number from each row in my 2d array. For example if a row looks like this: 3 5 1 3 11 2 afterwords it should look like 3 5 3 2. The 1 and 11 have been removed.

Comment: @Will I want to remove them from the array

Comment: I don't think you should start a and b with 0. Rather make both of them foo[0][0], because if there isn't a larger number than 0, zero will be the smallest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to store not only the value of the largest/shortest number but also its index. So at the end you are able to modify it.

Comment: But, what if I have repetition of numbers than wouldn't there be multiple indexes?

Comment: If you want to replace them all, you should make a second loop and check values against minimum and maximum

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
int foo[5][5]; //assume it is filled with postive numbers THERE ARE repeated numbers
int i, j; 
int a =foo[0][0] ; //biggest
int b = foo[0][0]; //smallest

for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
        if (a<foo[i][j])
            a = foo[i][j];
        if (b>foo[i][j])
            b = foo[i][j];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
        if (a==foo[i][j])
            foo[i][j] = 0;
        if (b==foo[i][j])
            foo[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your second for loop, I think you mean `if(a==foo[i][j])`, same for b.

Comment: Pretty much what Mohit said, what if you have 1 1 2 4 5 in a row. It will replace both 1s.

Comment: if `foo` is filled with positive numbers then you can't initialize `b` to zero. Nothing in `foo` will ever be smaller than zero, so `b` will never be set. You should initialize `a = INT_MIN;` and `b = INT_MAX;`, both defined in `limits.h`. That's as close as you can get to initializing to +/- infinity.

Comment: Actually, you also have the `a` and `b` comments backwards. Looking at your comparisons `a` will be the smallest value in the array. So flip my initializations.

Comment: @user2503935, I think you are confused with this question of yours, do you want to remove smallest and largest element from each row or from the whole of the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is what you need

```
int main(){
int foo[5][5]; //assume it is filled with positive numbers THERE ARE repeated numbers
int i, j, jmin, jmax; 


for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    int a = foo[i][0]; //biggest
    int b = foo[i][0]; //smallest

    for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        if (foo[i][j] > a)
        {
           a = foo[i][j];
           jmax = j;
        }
        if (foo[i][j] < b)
        {
           b = foo[i][j];
           jmin = j;
        }
    }

    foo[i][jmax] = 0;
    foo[i][jmin] = 0;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After understanding what you want, I am putting a new answer. Hope this helps.

I am replacing min. and max. of each row with a zero.

```
int main(){
int foo[5][5]; //assume it is filled with postive numbers THERE ARE repeated numbers
int i, j; 

for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
    int flagmin = 0, flagmax = 0;
    int rmin = f[i][0];
    int rmax = f[i][0];
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
        if (rmax < foo[i][j])
            rmax = foo[i][j];
        if (rmin > foo[i][j])
            rmin = foo[i][j];
    }
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
        if (rmax == foo[i][j] && flagmin = 0){
            flagmin = 1;
            foo[i][j] = 0;
        }
        if (rmin == foo[i][j] && flagmax = 0){
            flagmax = 1;
            foo[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```